# emacs JavsScript distable auto new lines

Tags: emacs

I use emacs edit js files, when I enter a `;`, it will auto jump a new line.

like this:

```
function test() {
    var x = 1;
    // <----- cursor auto in here !!!
}
```

How to disable it ?

Comment: What mode are you using?

Comment: js2-mode, but I use defaut emacs javascript-mode had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using electric-mode and have the auto-newline enabled.

Try evaluating this in a js buffer and see if it makes a difference (type <kbd>M-:</kbd> to eval):

```
(c-toggle-auto-newline 0)
```

If it does, just disable the electric mode in your setup or add that line to your js2-mode hook.